# Vlookup using two strings

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am using the Vlookup to pull data, but the data table row that I want data from may be using a different text string, I was hoping someone can help me out with the correct syntax to use (I can't get it to work) - this is what I have so far:

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP("String 1"&"String 2",'excelbook'!$A$2:$Y$75,B$407,FALSE),0)`

Would totally appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: Well.. we need to see the table you are trying to lookup in.  Also, it is good practice to NAME the range you are using as the lookup target.

Comment: Are you looking up a literal value "String 1String 2" ?  Maybe need to add a bit more detail to your question.

Comment: Does B$407 actually contain a number between 1-25 or do you need to `MATCH` a string value against a column header row? Sample data together with the expected results would have answered all of the questions posed back to you.

Comment: Hey guys, the answer below seems to have worked...
Basically, I am looking for "Revenue" in the table, then the vlookup simply posts the value to the right of that (like for year 2013).... but.... sometimes Revenue is called "Sales"... so basically I would need it to see if either or is listed in the table then to just grab the number to the right, which seems to be working right now...

B$407 is a number (like 1) so that I can easily drag the vlookup formula across to keep grabbing the Revenue from the other columns (years)..... 

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the row which contains `String 1`  OR  `String 2` in the first column, you can use the following formula:

```
=IFERROR( VLOOKUP("String 1",'excelbook'!$A$2:$Y$75,B$407,FALSE), IFERROR(VLOOKUP("String 2",'excelbook'!$A$2:$Y$75,B$407,FALSE),0) )
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Genius! You used the error true argument to find the other string, then you put 0 if it doesn't even find that one - thanks a lot!